# How to integrate PayPal sdk with Gradle Android

Tags: android, paypal, android-studio, payment-gateway, android-gradle-plugin

I want to know the steps of how to integrate PayPal sdk with Gradle Android. As read in the document, I imported the **.jar** file. then copied the **.so** files to JniLibs folder. But still the classes mention in the manifest are ion red color. *Ex com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService*

Comment: Does the SampleApp work correctly for you?  Your gradle file may not be configured to point to the correct libs folder.

Comment: hey check this; I haven't looked at the whole thing but it may have something that might help you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2e5vsouk4ce718/PayPal%20connect%20to%20Android%20App.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

you can use this dependency to integrate paypal trough gradle:

```
compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this latest dependency to integrate paypal trough gradle.

implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'